# MySQL Error pls-00103

Tags: mysql

I am making a MySQLand getting an error I dont know how to fix it. What the function should be doing is asking the user for input, this input should be stored in the corresponding variables and return a variable. But when i try run the function I am getting errors on the lines that store the variables. I am quite new to mySQL so i might be doing something stupid. Any help will be great thank you

This is is the mysql function

```
create or replace FUNCTION AD_AGENCY_INFO(agency_id in agency_id%type)
RETURN agency_id

DECLARE

  v_no_of_runs AD_AGENCY.NO_OF_AD_RUNS%TYPE = '&enter_number_of_Runs';
  v_credit_worthy AD_AGENCY.CREDIT_WORTHY%TYPE = '&enter_credit_worthy';
  v_available_slots AD_AGENCY.AVAILABLE_SLOTS%TYPE = '&enter_available_slots';
  v_status AD_AGENCY.STATUS%TYPE = '&enter_status';

BEGIN

  insert into ad_agency values (agency_id, v_no_of_runs, v_credit_worthy,v_available_slots, v_status);
  insert into ad (agency_id) values (agency_id);

 commit;

RETURN (agency_id));
 END AD_AGENCY_INFO;
```

The error that i am getting is the following and is the same for lines 7,8,9

```
Error(6,45): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:     := ( ; not null range default character The symbol ":= was inserted before "=" to continue.
```

Comment: Cool thanks that got it sorted!

Comment: I have posted it as answer to take it off from unanswered list and so removing from comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your declare statement(s) to be

```
v_no_of_runs AD_AGENCY.NO_OF_AD_RUNS%TYPE := '&enter_number_of_Runs'
```